# Calling Angular page within spring maven project

Tags: spring, angular, maven, authentication, controller

I am attempting to have a one deployable war file for my angular webapp, I follow a guide to setup Angular with Spring here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

I see here that the way it is calling the built-in login form is through the `LoginController`. However what if I have my own login html created in Angular and want to be called from within the java controller?

Answer (score 0):

- Angular application has index.html, you put this file along with associated code in the webapp folder, so when you launch your java application, it will launch this index.html,
- Now with Angular routing you can forward to your custom login page.
- in detail: when index.html of angular is loaded, app component is loaded, you can put  in its html to forward to login page